# Pass Arraylist from Fragment to RecyclerAdapter (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My project is set up like this:

Inside MainActivity I have a viewpager to change between 4 fragments:

1. Fragment, **2. Fragment**, 3. Fragment and 4. Fragment.

I do following inside 2. Fragment:

- Initialize recyclerview and adapter.
- Runs asynctask to fetch json
- Runs onJobFinishListener to add data from asynctask to an arraylist

[image]

What I need to do is to pass asList from inside 2. Fragment to the recyclerAdapter, so that I inside onBindViewHolder can set title in relation to the strings in the arraylist in 2. Fragment.

Fragment 2.:

```
public class CardViewTabelFragment extends Fragment implements jsonAsynctask.DataTabelFragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

RecyclerAdapter adapter2;

List<String> asList;

jsonAsynctask jsonasynctask;

public CardViewTabelFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.card_list, container, false );

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter( );

    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( getActivity() );

    ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setOrientation( LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL );

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( layoutManager );

    return view;

}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint( isVisibleToUser );

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        jsonasynctask = new jsonAsynctask( this );
        jsonasynctask.execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onJobFinishListener(List<String> allId) {

    asList = new ArrayList<String>( jsonasynctask.uniqueStrings );

    asList.add( 0, "ALLE SENSORER" );
    asList.add( "NÆSTE SENSORER" );

    System.out.println( "MEGET VIGTIGT DU KIGGER HER: " + asList );

    adapter2.addList(asList);
    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public RecyclerAdapter( List<String> linkedDevice ) {

    this.data = linkedDevice;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position) {

    recyclerViewHolder.mTitle.setText( data.get( position ) );
    recyclerViewHolder.mBeskrivelse.setText( OurData.beskrivelse[position] );
    //recyclerViewHolder.mTitle.setText( OurData.title[position] );
    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( OurData.colors[position] ) );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.data.size();
}
```

This is the EXCEPTION:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.yusuf.cxweb, PID: 13337
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
```

*** JSON ASYNCTASK ***

```
public class jsonAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

JSONObject deviceArray;
JSONArray json2;

String username = "xxx";
String password = "xxx";
String credentials = username + ":" + password;
String xxxURL = "https://" + credentials + "@xxx.com/fetch.php?";

String basicAuth, line, json_string, json, device;

String data = "";

List<String> asList;

LinkedHashSet<String> uniqueStrings = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

List<String> allDevice = new ArrayList<String>();

Gson gson;

HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

URL url;

private DataTabelFragment dataTabelFragment;

public jsonAsynctask(jsonAsynctask.DataTabelFragment dataTabelFragment) {

    this.dataTabelFragment = dataTabelFragment;

}

public void inBackground() {

    try {

        url = new URL( xxxURL );

        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        basicAuth = "Basic " + new String( encodeBase64URLSafeString( credentials.getBytes() ) );

        connection.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", basicAuth );
        connection.setRequestMethod( "GET" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Language", "en-US" );
        connection.setUseCaches( true );
        connection.setDoInput( true );
        connection.setDoOutput( true );
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( stream ) );

        line = "";

        while (line != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }

        json2 = new JSONArray( data );

        for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {

            deviceArray = json2.getJSONObject( i );

            device = deviceArray.getString( "device" );

            uniqueStrings.add( device );

            allDevice.add( device );

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData) {

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString( binaryData, android.util.Base64.URL_SAFE );

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    inBackground();

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute( aVoid );

    dataTabelFragment.onJobFinishListener( allDevice );

    gson = new Gson();

    json = gson.toJson( data );

    json_string = data;

}

public interface DataTabelFragment {

    void onJobFinishListener(List<String> allId);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? There is a lot of unrelated code here.

Comment: I need to pass the arraylist asList from 2. Fragment to the recyclerAdapter

Comment: so that when i mTitle.setText in onBindViewHolder, then the titles will be set after the strings inside asList

Comment: I'll gladly elaborate, if it still doesn't make any sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add a method to accept new list inside Recycler Adapter

`public void addList(List<String> linkedDevice){
    this.linkedDevice = linkedDevice;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}`

Also override getItemCount() as -

`@Override
 public int getItemCount() {
    return this.linkedDevice.size();
}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated your suggestion in my, but received an exception.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace @Yas

Answer (score 1):

You are using some static array to get the data and that seems wrong.

What you can do is to save your data in the adapter and change your `onBindViewHolder()` (the same goes for the other methods of the adapter that use the static data):

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position) {
    recyclerViewHolder.mBeskrivelse.setText(data[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

And in the fragment:

```
RecyclerAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onJobFinishListener(List<String> allId) {

    asList = new ArrayList<String>( jsonasynctask.uniqueStrings );
    asList.add( 0, "ALLE SENSORER" );
    asList.add( "NÆSTE SENSORER" );

    System.out.println( "MEGET VIGTIGT DU KIGGER HER: " + asList );
    adapter.setData(asList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated your suggestion, but received an exception. I have updated my codes in my thread

Comment: I changed my code to include the `getItemCount()` function. However, you should also make sure you replace all references to `OurData` inside your adapter as it is no longer used for getting the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how I didn't see that. Appreciated

Comment: Hi Doron, my 2. fragment becomes blank, when running. When I debugged I found out that my getItemCount = 0. I realize that the method is running, when the app is starting, and therefore the json Asynctask have no chance to update the getItemCount. Do you know what I can do? Thanks in advance!